# Is there an alternative to the `which` command?

Tags: software-rec, which

If the `which` command is not available, is there another 'standard' method to find out where a command's executable can be found?

If there is no other 'standard' method available, the actual system I face currently is a bare Android emulator with an `ash` [Almquist shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell), if that means anything.

Comment: See also [Why not use “which”? What to use then?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/22565)

Comment: @StephaneChazelas that may mean my question is a duplicate. I've tried to search for this question but I missed what you linked. thanks!

Comment: well, the other question is perhaps properly described with that `all you never thought you would ever not want to know about it` - this leaves some room for mine .  :)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This should be a standard solution:

```
type
type -t
type -p
```

Comment: you're right, it works, thank you, I forgot `type`. Is there a reference that declares it standard, by the way? like some document at opengroup. If there is, can you link it perhaps?

Comment: `type` and `command -V/v` are [standard (Unix, LSB, but optional in POSIX (XSI)](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/type.html), `type -p` and `type -t` are not.

Answer (score 3):

> whereis

Not quite the same, but should give you the binary's location like 'which' does.

Comment: good to know, thanks, but it in the current OS it does not work for me

Answer (score 3):

You can search the $PATH yourself to find a command:

```
COMMAND=vim # This is the command  to search for
(IFS=:; for dir in $PATH; do [ -x  $dir/$COMMAND ] && echo $dir/$COMMAND; done)
```

(this should work in `ash` and many other Bourne shell derivatives)

Comment: this is a good option if `[` is included on the target system.

Comment: If  your shell or keyboard doesn't support "[]" (I think ash does), you can replace `[ -x $dir/$COMMAND ]` with `test -x $dir/$COMMAND`  (test is a bash/ash built-in, and may also be available as a standalone executable

Comment: :) it's not actually my keyboard, my `ash` on this Android emulator seems *not* to come with either `[` or `test`. I'm not sure if I'm doing anything wrong, the system seems stock and reports `ash` for shell.

Comment: I would regard any shell without either `test` or `[`...`]` as unusable for any but the most limited purposes.